# How do I define an array with a variable using C?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to do something like this:

```
int a = 10;
int array[a];
```

---

(Is it correct / good practice? )

---

But when I do that and test it with:

```
printf("%d", sizeof(array));
```

I get an array with length of 40. Is it make sense?

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @immibis, can you explain what does sizeof really do?

Comment: It returns the size of an object in bytes.

Comment: `%zu` should be used for outputting the result of `sizeof`

Comment: why does this have 2 votes as "unclear" ?

Comment: Thanks @immibis for the explanation! What I really wanted was (int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])).

Comment: I don't know, @MattMcNabb. It's Stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is legal C99.

However, compiler support for that functionality (called Variable Length Arrays or VLAs for short) is somewhat spotty.  For example, Microsoft Visual Studio doesn't implement it.  Also, C11 made VLAs an optional part of the standard, so this code won't be as portable as possible.

Regardless, your compiler seems to support it and, yes, a size of `40` makes sense if your `int` size is **32 bits**, which is common, as `4 * 10 = 40`

Comment: Reading between the lines, it is portable for every compiler except MSVC who have no interest in updating their C compiler

Comment: @MattMcNabb Basically true, but I bet some compilers for esoteric hardware will never bother implementing VLAs now that C11 made them optional.  That is assuming they ever advance away from C90, which is itself a dubious proposition. :)